# How to create database view with cutom LIKE parameter?

Tags: java, mysql, database, sql-view

I have JDBC Connection to my cloud MySQL database.
Utilizing the benefit of View's fetch time, I decided to create view for my user-queried searched results to be added into my JavaFX UI TableView.

I have following SQL View to run from method in UI.

```sql
    CREATE VIEW `SEARCHED_QUERY_VIEW` AS
    SELECT PRODUCTS.id, 
    PRODUCTS.name AS 'Product name',
    MANUFACTURER.name AS 'Manufacturer name',
    PACKAGE.name AS 'Package type',
    SUB_PACKAGE.name AS 'Sub Package type' 
    FROM LOGISTICS.PRODUCTS
    JOIN MANUFACTURER ON PRODUCTS.manid = MANUFACTURER.id 
    JOIN PACKAGE ON PRODUCTS.packageid = PACKAGE.id
    JOIN SUB_PACKAGE ON PRODUCTS.subpackageid = SUB_PACKAGE.id
    WHERE MANUFACTURER.name LIKE '%VIT%' OR PRODUCTS.name LIKE '%VIT%';
```

Now the problem lies with `LIKE` here.
I want `LIKE` to get an argument which will be passed from a parameterized method in JavaFX.
Can anybody advise solution on how to rework the view to receive custom `LIKE` parameter from Java Method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move like parameter to select from the View.
So create the View without like condition but use LIKE in the query:

```
SELECT * FROM SEARCHED_QUERY_VIEW WHERE `Manufacturer name` LIKE '%VIT%' OR `Product name` LIKE '%VIT%';
```

Comment: Will querying LIKE later save my fetching time?

Comment: View gives you convenient way to select the data, it gives you ability to change tables and view without java code modification (in some cases). Unfortunately fetching time probably will be the same as for simple query with joins.

Comment: "fetching time probably will be the same as for simple query with joins" - In best case!

Comment: Also: You can't use `MANUFACTURER.name` and `PRODUCTS.name` - The tables are unknown in that context.

Comment: @Paul Spiegel Thank you! I fixed the answer.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Oh, I just realized that thing! I can't use MANUFACTURER.name from that context. Any other work around?

Comment: You can use fields from the View.
I have fixed the answer,  have a look.

Comment: @i.bondarenko Yep, that worked. Thanks to all. Appreciate the efforts!

Comment: but my suggestion is to rename view fields aliases `Manufacturer name' -> manufacturer_name and 'Product name' -> product_name

Comment: @i.bondarenko Yes, I will. They are not much significant to user anyways.